# Switch between channel 1 and channel 2 in Tmediaplayer

Tags: tmediaplayer

Running Delphi 7 on a XP (SP4) I have finally made my TMediaplayer create and play different tones (eg. 440 Hz , 550 HZ ..  1000 Hz ). But the code is only working in the right channel. Is it possible in code to select the output between to the left channel or right channel, repectively ??   If so, can anyone help ? Thanks in advance.   Kris